# Refreshable Indicator is presented on view's appear

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, refresh

Once a view appears refreshable indicator is already visible without the necessity of performing the swipe on list. When I swipe the list up it hides and then pull to refresh can be performed in correct way (it shows, performs actions and hide).

My View:

```
struct OrdersView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var tabBarStateManager: TabBarStateManager
    @EnvironmentObject private var profileViewModel: ProfileViewModel
    
    @StateObject private var ordersViewModel: OrdersViewModel = OrdersViewModel()
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss: DismissAction
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(ordersViewModel.datesForOrdersViewListSections, id: \.self) { stringDate in
                Section {
                    ForEach(ordersViewModel.getOrdersFor(date: stringDate), id: \.self) { order in
                        NavigationLink(destination: OrderDetailsView(order: order,
                                                                     orderProductsList: ordersViewModel.getOrderProductsFor(order: order))
                                                                                            .environmentObject(ordersViewModel)) {
                            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
                                HStack(spacing: 10) {
                                    Text(order.id)
                                        .font(.ssCallout)
                                    Spacer()
                                    Text(Date.getDayAndMonthFrom(date: order.orderDate))
                                        .font(.ssTitle3)
                                        .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                                }
                                
                                Text("$\(order.totalCost, specifier: "%.2f")")
                                    .font(.ssTitle3)
                                    .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                                
                                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                    HStack {
                                        Text(TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .ordersView(.products)))
                                            .font(.ssCallout)
                                        Text("\(ordersViewModel.getOrderProductsFor(order: order).count)")
                                            .font(.ssTitle3)
                                            .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                                    }
                                        
                                    HStack {
                                        Text(TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .ordersView(.orderStatus)))
                                            .font(.ssCallout)
                                        Text(order.status.rawValue)
                                            .font(.ssTitle3)
                                            .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            .padding(.vertical)
                        }
                    }
                } header: {
                    Text(stringDate)
                        .font(.ssTitle1)
                        .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                }
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.grouped)
        .refreshable {
            profileViewModel.fetchUserOrders {
                ordersViewModel.userOrders = profileViewModel.userOrders
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle(TexterifyManager.localisedString(key: .ordersView(.navigationTitle)))
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                Button {
                    dismiss()
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.backward.circle.fill")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                        .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            ordersViewModel.userOrders = profileViewModel.userOrders
        }
    }
}
```

Changing `.refreshable` modifier order does not fix the problem
Changing `.listStyle` also does not help

The problem only occurs on physical device on iPhone 13 Pro Max (iOS 16.1). The same version of simulator does not have the problem.

EDIT:
I discovered that my problem only occurs when `.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode` is set to `.inline` instead of default `.large`

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example implementation, not exactly yours because you have complex structures that I was not able to reproduce. I hope you get some good from this example:

```swift
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  Refreshable
//
//  Created by Allan Garcia on 11/11/22.
//

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var isLoading = true
    // You may start the view starting with a loading state, before the data was loaded
    
    @State private var myList = [String]() { 
        didSet {
            isLoading = false
        }
    }
    // Once the data is set isLoading (the loading state) is turned off
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                if isLoading {
                    ProgressView()
                        .progressViewStyle(.circular)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                }
                ForEach(myList, id: \.self) { item in
                    Text(item)
                }
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .onAppear {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    isLoading = true
                    withAnimation {
                        self.myList = ContentView.fetchedList[0..<10].map { $0.uppercased() }
                    }
                }
                // On Appear you will probably fetch "some" data with pagination
            }
            .refreshable { 
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    withAnimation {
                        self.myList = ContentView.fetchedList.map { $0.uppercased() }
                        // A note here... refreshable is good when new data comes on top. If the data comes from bellow is
                        // a infinite scrolling approach much more advisable.
                    }
                }
                // .refreshable works fine here... ir will fetch more data... here it fetchs all, but is probably a
                // good practice to fetch "some" more, and let the user read through until he wants to fetch more and
                // trigger refreshable again.
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    static let fetchedList = ["a","abandon","ability","able","abortion","about","above","abroad","absence","absolute","absolutely","absorb","abuse","academic","accept","access","accident","accompany","accomplish","according","account","accurate","accuse","achieve","achievement","acid","acknowledge","acquire","across","act","action","active","activist","activity","actor","actress","actual","actually","ad","adapt","add","addition","additional","address","adequate","adjust","adjustment","administration","administrator","admire","admission","admit","adolescent","adopt","adult","advance","advanced","advantage","adventure","advertising","advice","advise","adviser","advocate","affair","affect","afford","afraid","African","African-American","after","afternoon","again","against","age","agency","agenda","agent","aggressive","ago","agree","agreement","agricultural","ah","ahead","aid","aide","AIDS","aim","air","aircraft","airline","airport","album","alcohol","alive","all","alliance","allow","ally","almost","alone","along","already","also","alter","alternative","although","always","AM","amazing","American","among","amount","analysis","analyst","analyze","ancient","and","anger","angle","angry","animal","anniversary","announce","annual","another","answer","anticipate","anxiety","any","anybody","anymore","anyone","anything","anyway","anywhere","apart","apartment","apparent","apparently","appeal","appear","appearance","apple","application","apply","appoint","appointment","appreciate","approach","appropriate","approval","approve","approximately","Arab","architect","area","argue","argument","arise","arm","armed","army","around","arrange","arrangement","arrest","arrival","arrive","art","article","artist","artistic","as","Asian","aside","ask","asleep","aspect","assault","assert","assess","assessment","asset","assign","assignment","assist","assistance","assistant","associate","association","assume","assumption","assure","at","athlete","athletic","atmosphere","attach","attack","attempt","attend","attention","attitude","attorney","attract","attractive","attribute","audience","author","authority","auto","available","average","avoid","award","aware","awareness","away","awful","baby","back","background","bad","badly","bag","bake","balance","ball","ban","band","bank","bar","barely","barrel","barrier","base","baseball","basic","basically","basis","basket","basketball","bathroom","battery","battle","be","beach","bean","bear","beat","beautiful","beauty","because","become","bed","bedroom","beer","before","begin","beginning","behavior","behind","being","belief","believe","bell","belong","below","belt","bench","bend","beneath","benefit","beside","besides","best","bet","better","between","beyond","Bible","big","bike","bill","billion","bind","biological","bird","birth","birthday","bit","bite","black","blade","blame","blanket","blind","block","blood","blow","blue","board","boat","body","bomb","bombing","bond","bone","book","boom","boot","border","born","borrow","boss","both","bother","bottle","bottom","boundary","bowl","box","boy","boyfriend","brain","branch","brand","bread","break","breakfast","breast","breath","breathe","brick","bridge","brief","briefly","bright","brilliant","bring","British","broad","broken","brother","brown","brush","buck","budget","build","building","bullet","bunch","burden","burn","bury","bus","business","busy","but","butter","button","buy","buyer","by","cabin","cabinet","cable","cake","calculate","call","camera","camp","campaign","campus","can","Canadian","cancer","candidate","cap","capability","capable","capacity","capital","captain","capture","car","carbon","card","care","career","careful","carefully","carrier","carry","case","cash","cast","cat","catch","category","Catholic","cause","ceiling","celebrate","celebration","celebrity","cell","center","central","century","CEO","ceremony","certain","certainly","chain","chair","chairman","challenge","chamber","champion","championship","chance","change","changing","channel","chapter","character","characteristic","characterize","charge","charity","chart","chase","cheap","check","cheek","cheese","chef","chemical","chest","chicken","chief","child","childhood","Chinese","chip","chocolate","choice","cholesterol","choose","Christian","Christmas","church","cigarette","circle","circumstance","cite","citizen","city","civil","civilian","claim","class","classic","classroom","clean","clear","clearly","client","climate","climb","clinic","clinical","clock","close","closely","closer","clothes","clothing","cloud","club","clue","cluster","coach","coal","coalition","coast","coat","code","coffee","cognitive","cold","collapse","colleague","collect","collection","collective","college","colonial","color","column","combination","combine","come","comedy","comfort","comfortable","command","commander","comment","commercial","commission","commit","commitment","committee","common","communicate","communication","community","company","compare","comparison","compete","competition","competitive","competitor","complain","complaint","complete","completely","complex","complicated","component","compose","composition","comprehensive","computer","concentrate","concentration","concept","concern","concerned","concert","conclude","conclusion","concrete","condition","conduct","conference","confidence","confident","confirm","conflict","confront","confusion","Congress","congressional","connect","connection","consciousness","consensus","consequence","conservative","consider","considerable","consideration","consist","consistent","constant","constantly","constitute","constitutional","construct","construction","consultant","consume","consumer","consumption","contact","contain","container","contemporary","content","contest","context","continue","continued","contract","contrast","contribute","contribution","control","controversial","controversy","convention","conventional","conversation","convert","conviction","convince","cook","cookie","cooking","cool","cooperation","cop","cope","copy","core","corn","corner","corporate","corporation","correct","correspondent","cost","cotton","couch","could","council","counselor","count","counter","country","county","couple","courage","course","court","cousin","cover","coverage","cow","crack","craft","crash","crazy","cream","create","creation","creative","creature","credit","crew","crime","criminal","crisis","criteria","critic","critical","criticism","criticize","crop","cross","crowd","crucial","cry","cultural","culture","cup","curious","current","currently","curriculum","custom","customer","cut","cycle","dad","daily","damage","dance","danger","dangerous","dare","dark","darkness","data","date","daughter","day","dead","deal","dealer","dear","death","debate","debt","decade","decide","decision","deck","declare","decline","decrease","deep","deeply","deer","defeat","defend","defendant","defense","defensive","deficit","define","definitely","definition","degree","delay","deliver","delivery","demand","democracy","Democrat","democratic","demonstrate","demonstration","deny","department","depend","dependent","depending","depict","depression","depth","deputy","derive","describe","description","desert","deserve","design","designer","desire","desk","desperate","despite","destroy","destruction","detail","detailed","detect","determine","develop","developing","development","device","devote","dialogue","die","diet","differ","difference","different","differently","difficult","difficulty","dig","digital","dimension","dining","dinner","direct","direction","directly","director","dirt","dirty","disability","disagree","disappear","disaster","discipline","discourse","discover","discovery","discrimination","discuss","discussion","disease","dish","dismiss","disorder","display","dispute","distance","distant","distinct","distinction","distinguish","distribute","distribution","district","diverse","diversity","divide","division","divorce","DNA","do","doctor","document","dog","domestic","dominant","dominate","door","double","doubt","down","downtown","dozen","draft","drag","drama","dramatic","dramatically","draw","drawing","dream","dress","drink","drive","driver","drop","drug","dry","due","during","dust","duty","each","eager","ear","early","earn","earnings","earth","ease","easily","east","eastern","easy","eat","economic","economics","economist","economy","edge","edition","editor","educate","education","educational","educator","effect","effective","effectively","efficiency","efficient","effort","egg","eight","either","elderly","elect","election","electric","electricity","electronic","element","elementary","eliminate","elite","else","elsewhere","e-mail","embrace","emerge","emergency","emission","emotion","emotional","emphasis","emphasize","employ","employee","employer","employment","empty","enable","encounter","encourage","end","enemy","energy","enforcement","engage","engine","engineer","engineering","English","enhance","enjoy","enormous","enough","ensure","enter","enterprise","entertainment","entire","entirely","entrance","entry","environment","environmental","episode","equal","equally","equipment","era","error","escape","especially","essay","essential","essentially","establish","establishment","estate","estimate","etc","ethics","ethnic","European","evaluate","evaluation","even","evening","event","eventually","ever","every","everybody","everyday","everyone","everything","everywhere","evidence","evolution","evolve","exact","exactly","examination","examine","example","exceed","excellent","except","exception","exchange","exciting","executive","exercise","exhibit","exhibition","exist","existence","existing","expand","expansion","expect","expectation","expense","expensive","experience","experiment","expert","explain","explanation","explode","explore","explosion","expose","exposure","express","expression","extend","extension","extensive","extent","external","extra","extraordinary","extreme","extremely","eye","fabric","face","facility","fact","factor","factory","faculty","fade","fail","failure","fair","fairly","faith","fall","false","familiar","family","famous","fan","fantasy","far","farm","farmer","fashion","fast","fat","fate","father","fault","favor","favorite","fear","feature","federal","fee","feed","feel","feeling","fellow","female","fence","few","fewer","fiber","fiction","field","fifteen","fifth","fifty","fight","fighter","fighting","figure","file","fill","film","final","finally","finance","financial","find","finding","fine","finger","finish","fire","firm","first","fish","fishing","fit","fitness","five","fix","flag","flame","flat","flavor","flee","flesh","flight","float","floor","flow","flower","fly","focus","folk","follow","following","food","foot","football","for","force","foreign","forest","forever","forget","form","formal","formation","former","formula","forth","fortune","forward","found","foundation","founder","four","fourth","frame","framework","free","freedom","freeze","French","frequency","frequent","frequently","fresh","friend","friendly","friendship","from","front","fruit","frustration","fuel","full","fully","fun","function","fund","fundamental","funding","funeral","funny","furniture","furthermore","future","gain","galaxy","gallery","game","gang","gap","garage","garden","garlic","gas","gate","gather","gay","gaze","gear","gender","gene","general","generally","generate","generation","genetic","gentleman","gently","German","gesture","get","ghost","giant","gift","gifted","girl","girlfriend","give","given","glad","glance","glass","global","glove","go","goal","God","gold","golden","golf","good","government","governor","grab","grade","gradually","graduate","grain","grand","grandfather","grandmother","grant","grass","grave","gray","great","greatest","green","grocery","ground","group","grow","growing","growth","guarantee","guard","guess","guest","guide","guideline","guilty","gun","guy","habit","habitat","hair","half","hall","hand","handful","handle","hang","happen","happy","hard","hardly","hat","hate","have","he","head","headline","headquarters","health","healthy","hear","hearing","heart","heat","heaven","heavily","heavy","heel","height","helicopter","hell","hello","help","helpful","her","here","heritage","hero","herself","hey","hi","hide","high","highlight","highly","highway","hill","him","himself","hip","hire","his","historian","historic","historical","history","hit","hold","hole","holiday","holy","home","homeless","honest","honey","honor","hope","horizon","horror","horse","hospital","host","hot","hotel","hour","house","household","housing","how","however","huge","human","humor","hundred","hungry","hunter","hunting","hurt","husband","hypothesis","I","ice","idea","ideal","identification","identify","identity","ie","if","ignore","ill","illegal","illness","illustrate","image","imagination","imagine","immediate","immediately","immigrant","immigration","impact","implement","implication","imply","importance","important","impose","impossible","impress","impression","impressive","improve","improvement","in","incentive","incident","include","including","income","incorporate","increase","increased","increasing","increasingly","incredible","indeed","independence","independent","index","Indian","indicate","indication","individual","industrial","industry","infant","infection","inflation","influence","inform","information","ingredient","initial","initially","initiative","injury","inner","innocent","inquiry","inside","insight","insist","inspire","install","instance","instead","institution","institutional","instruction","instructor","instrument","insurance","intellectual","intelligence","intend","intense","intensity","intention","interaction","interest","interested","interesting","internal","international","Internet","interpret","interpretation","intervention","interview","into","introduce","introduction","invasion","invest","investigate","investigation","investigator","investment","investor","invite","involve","involved","involvement","Iraqi","Irish","iron","Islamic","island","Israeli","issue","it","Italian","item","its","itself","jacket","jail","Japanese","jet","Jew","Jewish","job","join","joint","joke","journal","journalist","journey","joy","judge","judgment","juice","jump","junior","jury","just","justice","justify","keep","key","kick","kid","kill","killer","killing","kind","king","kiss","kitchen","knee","knife","knock","know","knowledge","lab","label","labor","laboratory","lack","lady","lake","land","landscape","language","lap","large","largely","last","late","later","Latin","latter","laugh","launch","law","lawn","lawsuit","lawyer","lay","layer","lead","leader","leadership","leading","leaf","league","lean","learn","learning","least","leather","leave","left","leg","legacy","legal","legend","legislation","legitimate","lemon","length","less","lesson","let","letter","level","liberal","library","license","lie","life","lifestyle","lifetime","lift","light","like","likely","limit","limitation","limited","line","link","lip","list","listen","literally","literary","literature","little","live","living","load","loan","local","locate","location","lock","long","long-term","look","loose","lose","loss","lost","lot","lots","loud","love","lovely","lover","low","lower","luck","lucky","lunch","lung","machine","mad","magazine","mail","main","mainly","maintain","maintenance","major","majority","make","maker","makeup","male","mall","man","manage","management","manager","manner","manufacturer","manufacturing","many","map","margin","mark","market","marketing","marriage","married","marry","mask","mass","massive","master","match","material","math","matter","may","maybe","mayor","me","meal","mean","meaning","meanwhile","measure","measurement","meat","mechanism","media","medical","medication","medicine","medium","meet","meeting","member","membership","memory","mental","mention","menu","mere","merely","mess","message","metal","meter","method","Mexican","middle","might","military","milk","million","mind","mine","minister","minor","minority","minute","miracle","mirror","miss","missile","mission","mistake","mix","mixture","mm-hmm","mode","model","moderate","modern","modest","mom","moment","money","monitor","month","mood","moon","moral","more","moreover","morning","mortgage","most","mostly","mother","motion","motivation","motor","mount","mountain","mouse","mouth","move","movement","movie","Mr","Mrs","Ms","much","multiple","murder","muscle","museum","music","musical","musician","Muslim","must","mutual","my","myself","mystery","myth","naked","name","narrative","narrow","nation","national","native","natural","naturally","nature","near","nearby","nearly","necessarily","necessary","neck","need","negative","negotiate","negotiation","neighbor","neighborhood","neither","nerve","nervous","net","network","never","nevertheless","new","newly","news","newspaper","next","nice","night","nine","no","nobody","nod","noise","nomination","none","nonetheless","nor","normal","normally","north","northern","nose","not","note","nothing","notice","notion","novel","now","nowhere","n't","nuclear","number","numerous","nurse","nut","object","objective","obligation","observation","observe","observer","obtain","obvious","obviously","occasion","occasionally","occupation","occupy","occur","ocean","odd","odds","of","off","offense","offensive","offer","office","officer","official","often","oh","oil","ok","okay","old","Olympic","on","once","one","ongoing","onion","online","only","onto","open","opening","operate","operating","operation","operator","opinion","opponent","opportunity","oppose","opposite","opposition","option","or","orange","order","ordinary","organic","organization","organize","orientation","origin","original","originally","other","others","otherwise","ought","our","ourselves","out","outcome","outside","oven","over","overall","overcome","overlook","owe","own","owner","pace","pack","package","page","pain","painful","paint","painter","painting","pair","pale","Palestinian","palm","pan","panel","pant","paper","parent","park","parking","part","participant","participate","participation","particular","particularly","partly","partner","partnership","party","pass","passage","passenger","passion","past","patch","path","patient","pattern","pause","pay","payment","PC","peace","peak","peer","penalty","people","pepper","per","perceive","percentage","perception","perfect","perfectly","perform","performance","perhaps","period","permanent","permission","permit","person","personal","personality","personally","personnel","perspective","persuade","pet","phase","phenomenon","philosophy","phone","photo","photograph","photographer","phrase","physical","physically","physician","piano","pick","picture","pie","piece","pile","pilot","pine","pink","pipe","pitch","place","plan","plane","planet","planning","plant","plastic","plate","platform","play","player","please","pleasure","plenty","plot","plus","PM","pocket","poem","poet","poetry","point","pole","police","policy","political","politically","politician","politics","poll","pollution","pool","poor","pop","popular","population","porch","port","portion","portrait","portray","pose","position","positive","possess","possibility","possible","possibly","post","pot","potato","potential","potentially","pound","pour","poverty","powder","power","powerful","practical","practice","pray","prayer","precisely","predict","prefer","preference","pregnancy","pregnant","preparation","prepare","prescription","presence","present","presentation","preserve","president","presidential","press","pressure","pretend","pretty","prevent","previous","previously","price","pride","priest","primarily","primary","prime","principal","principle","print","prior","priority","prison","prisoner","privacy","private","probably","problem","procedure","proceed","process","produce","producer","product","production","profession","professional","professor","profile","profit","program","progress","project","prominent","promise","promote","prompt","proof","proper","properly","property","proportion","proposal","propose","proposed","prosecutor","prospect","protect","protection","protein","protest","proud","prove","provide","provider","province","provision","psychological","psychologist","psychology","public","publication","publicly","publish","publisher","pull","punishment","purchase","pure","purpose","pursue","push","put","qualify","quality","quarter","quarterback","question","quick","quickly","quiet","quietly","quit","quite","quote","race","racial","radical","radio","rail","rain","raise","range","rank","rapid","rapidly","rare","rarely","rate","rather","rating","ratio","raw","reach","react","reaction","read","reader","reading","ready","real","reality","realize","really","reason","reasonable","recall","receive","recent","recently","recipe","recognition","recognize","recommend","recommendation","record","recording","recover","recovery","recruit","red","reduce","reduction","refer","reference","reflect","reflection","reform","refugee","refuse","regard","regarding","regardless","regime","region","regional","register","regular","regularly","regulate","regulation","reinforce","reject","relate","relation","relationship","relative","relatively","relax","release","relevant","relief","religion","religious","rely","remain","remaining","remarkable","remember","remind","remote","remove","repeat","repeatedly","replace","reply","report","reporter","represent","representation","representative","Republican","reputation","request","require","requirement","research","researcher","resemble","reservation","resident","resist","resistance","resolution","resolve","resort","resource","respect","respond","respondent","response","responsibility","responsible","rest","restaurant","restore","restriction","result","retain","retire","retirement","return","reveal","revenue","review","revolution","rhythm","rice","rich","rid","ride","rifle","right","ring","rise","risk","river","road","rock","role","roll","romantic","roof","room","root","rope","rose","rough","roughly","round","route","routine","row","rub","rule","run","running","rural","rush","Russian","sacred","sad","safe","safety","sake","salad","salary","sale","sales","salt","same","sample","sanction","sand","satellite","satisfaction","satisfy","sauce","save","saving","say","scale","scandal","scared","scenario","scene","schedule","scheme","scholar","scholarship","school","science","scientific","scientist","scope","score","scream","screen","script","sea","search","season","seat","second","secret","secretary","section","sector","secure","security","see","seed","seek","seem","segment","seize","select","selection","self","sell","Senate","senator","send","senior","sense","sensitive","sentence","separate","sequence","series","serious","seriously","serve","service","session","set","setting","settle","settlement","seven","several","severe","sex","sexual","shade","shadow","shake","shall","shape","share","sharp","she","sheet","shelf","shell","shelter","shift","shine","ship","shirt","shit","shock","shoe","shoot","shooting","shop","shopping","shore","short","shortly","shot","should","shoulder","shout","show","shower","shrug","shut","sick","side","sigh","sight","sign","signal","significance","significant","significantly","silence","silent","silver","similar","similarly","simple","simply","sin","since","sing","singer","single","sink","sir","sister","sit","site","situation","six","size","ski","skill","skin","sky","slave","sleep","slice","slide","slight","slightly","slip","slow","slowly","small","smart","smell","smile","smoke","smooth","snap","snow","so","so-called","soccer","social","society","soft","software","soil","solar","soldier","solid","solution","solve","some","somebody","somehow","someone","something","sometimes","somewhat","somewhere","son","song","soon","sophisticated","sorry","sort","soul","sound","soup","source","south","southern","Soviet","space","Spanish","speak","speaker","special","specialist","species","specific","specifically","speech","speed","spend","spending","spin","spirit","spiritual","split","spokesman","sport","spot","spread","spring","square","squeeze","stability","stable","staff","stage","stair","stake","stand","standard","standing","star","stare","start","state","statement","station","statistics","status","stay","steady","steal","steel","step","stick","still","stir","stock","stomach","stone","stop","storage","store","storm","story","straight","strange","stranger","strategic","strategy","stream","street","strength","strengthen","stress","stretch","strike","string","strip","stroke","strong","strongly","structure","struggle","student","studio","study","stuff","stupid","style","subject","submit","subsequent","substance","substantial","succeed","success","successful","successfully","such","sudden","suddenly","sue","suffer","sufficient","sugar","suggest","suggestion","suicide","suit","summer","summit","sun","super","supply","support","supporter","suppose","supposed","Supreme","sure","surely","surface","surgery","surprise","surprised","surprising","surprisingly","surround","survey","survival","survive","survivor","suspect","sustain","swear","sweep","sweet","swim","swing","switch","symbol","symptom","system","table","tablespoon","tactic","tail","take","tale","talent","talk","tall","tank","tap","tape","target","task","taste","tax","taxpayer","tea","teach","teacher","teaching","team","tear","teaspoon","technical","technique","technology","teen","teenager","telephone","telescope","television","tell","temperature","temporary","ten","tend","tendency","tennis","tension","tent","term","terms","terrible","territory","terror","terrorism","terrorist","test","testify","testimony","testing","text","than","thank","thanks","that","the","theater","their","them","theme","themselves","then","theory","therapy","there","therefore","these","they","thick","thin","thing","think","thinking","third","thirty","this","those","though","thought","thousand","threat","threaten","three","throat","through","throughout","throw","thus","ticket","tie","tight","time","tiny","tip","tire","tired","tissue","title","to","tobacco","today","toe","together","tomato","tomorrow","tone","tongue","tonight","too","tool","tooth","top","topic"]
    
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, unfortunately it does not help.
I discovered that my problem only occurs when `.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode` is set to `.inline` instead of default `.large`